# Confused: ajax sending request to a json file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, post

Just now I found some code in a webpage which confuses me a lot:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "/foo/bar/save.json",
        data: {
                key: value
              },
        type: "POST",
        success: function(a) {
                //some code
                },
        error: function(a) {
                //some code
                },
        dataType: "json"
       })
```

I know that it sends `data` to `url` using HTTP method `POST`, if the url is like `/foo/bar/save.php` or `/foo/bar/save` then there's no problem, but it ends with `.json`... 
What kind of server-side languages can handle requests sent to a path ended with `json`?
Does `json` have any special meanings or is it just the same as `.action` `.do` which I can rename as whatever I like?

Thanks!

Comment: If there's a controller or a node.js route or something similar on the other end, the url can be pretty much anything, there's no guarantee that the URL is an actual JSON file.

Comment: @adeneo aha, so I can rename it to anything else like `.nosj`? BTW, is there any server language using `.json` as file name?

Comment: The .json file extension is commonly used for JSON files in most enviroments, but the URL does not have to reference a file, the URL can be anything you'd like it to be, as long as the webserver on the other end catches that URL. In Apache URL's are commonly routed to files automatically for convenience, but it doesn't have to be a file, it can be a "catch all" webserver that dynamically creates content for any URL etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What kind of server-side languages can handle requests sent to a path ended with json?

Any. There is no need for a server to use file extensions to map URLs onto programs (or files).

> Does json have any special meanings

Using it in a URL hints (without even having to make the request) at the data type being returned (instead of how the software used to produce it was written). This is much more useful to people using clients to fetch the data.

Comment: This helps! So, is it a preferred practice that using URL as hints to the data type being returned? Is it easier for cooperation if I use `.json` ending URL everywhere it returns json data?

Comment: I'm not sure if it is preferred, but it make sense. It also avoids tying the URL to the technology which means a change of technology will either [make the urls change](http://www.w3.org/Provider/Style/URI.html) or confuse your developers by (e.g.) having a JSP file extension on a URL handled by a Perl program.

Answer (score 3):

> What kind of server-side languages can handle requests sent to a path ended with json?

Any kind.

This is just an url, the way it is handled, redirected or rewritten by the server is not shown to the client.

As an example, using a standard `apache / php` setup, you can have a rewrite rule on the server :

```
^(.*)\.json     $1.php?json=true
```

and have your content dynamically generated by a php script.